# How are hybrid parameters defined?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current, ac, dc

I was reading about H-Paramters and how they were essentially defined and couldn't quite understand this bit in the picture below.
Here are my questions:

- Shouldn't **Δv_BE = Δv_be** as **V_BE** is constant (DC) and **Δv_be** is variable (AC), how did it become just **v_be** (same for the other currents/voltages).
- In each paramter why did the condition variable (ex: **v_CE = constant** in **h11**) go from being a constant to being 0.
- Shouldn't the variables shown on the circuits be the total ones not just the AC variables (**v_eb** should be **v_BE**)?[image]

Answer (score 0):

For any linear two-port, we can define the h-parameters according to the equation

$$\begin{pmatrix}v_1 \\ i_2\end{pmatrix} =
  \begin{pmatrix} h_{11} & h_{12} \\ h_{21} & h_{22} \end{pmatrix}
  \begin{pmatrix} i_1 \\ v_2 \end{pmatrix}$$

In the case of the BJT in the common-emitter configuration, we're taking \$v_1\$ to be between the base and common (emitter) terminals, and \$v_2\$ to be between the collector and common terminals. According to the passive current convention, the port currents \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$ are then the currents in to the base and in to the collector, respectively.

> Shouldn't **Δv_BE = Δv_be** as **V_BE** is constant (DC) and **Δv_be** is variable (AC), how did it become just **v_be** (same for the other currents/voltages).

This is just a matter of notation chosen by the author of your textbook. It's common to use upper case \$V\$ for the DC voltage and lower case \$v\$ for the ac small-signal variation about the bias point. But I'm not aware of any convention that says the subscript must also be lower case for the small signal parameter.

> In each paramter why did the condition variable (ex: **v_CE = constant** in **h11**) go from being a constant to being 0.

Because \$h_11\$ (for example) is telling you about the response of \$v_1\$ due to stimulus from \$i_1\$ (\$i_B\$). If you want to know how \$v_1\$ varies in response to stimulus at \$v_2\$ (\$v_{CE}\$) you need to look at the \$h_{12}\$ parameter instead of \$h_{11}\$.

> Shouldn't the variables shown on the circuits be the total ones not just the AC variables (**v_eb** should be **v_BE**)?

No, the h-parameters can only describe a linear circuit, or, in this case, a linear approximation to the circuit's behavior when driven with a small-signal stimulus about a bias point.

The response of the "total" variables like \$V_{BE}\$ and \$I_C\$ isn't linear, so it can't be described by h-parameters.

Comment: I know this, my questions were about how they deducted these parameters from the total differential equation, I don't think you quite understood my 3 questions.

Answer (score 0):

- I agree with you. The first equation (including DC values) is somewhat misleading. For example: What is the difference between v_BE and v_be ? Example: V_BE=0.7 V and v_be=0.1 volts. Result: v_BE=0.8  volts. How should we interprete this value? Peak value ?

  Therefore, forget the first line and start with the next two equations for vbe and ic.
- This also answers the next 2 questions, I think.
- The situation is rather simple:

- We can expect that the differential voltage between B and E will have a certain relationship to the flowing diff. curent ib and - perhaps? We do not know from the start - also to the output diff. voltage vce. And we define some corresponding factors h11 and h12.

- A similar consideration applies to the current ic which leads to the other two factors h21 and h22.
- Now - to describe these 4 factors (find a name) and to derive a method to measure/simulate these factors, it is necessary to define in some cases an output short for diff. quantities (v_ce=0) or an open input for diff. quantities (ib=0), respectively. That`s all.
- Therefore, what is the purpose of all the equations below the equivalent small circuit diagram? They result in the 4 equations defining the 4 parameters h11, h12, h21, h22. However, these 4 equations follow already directly from the known 4-pole equations for vbe and ic.